# Why is the word "such" used in this sentence

Tags: word-usage

Jack London, who is the author is describing a Husky and how, unlike the man, it does not have an explicit concept of extremely cold temperatures. Rather, it merely senses danger.

> Possibly in its brain there was no sharp consciousness of a condition of very cold such as was in the man's brain.

What confuses me is the usage of "such as was". Intuitively, I understood the sentence, but I would like to know exactly why it is worded the way it is.

Comment: I'm not sure if it's "such as" introducing a list of examples, but is rather "[such](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/such)" meaning "of a/the kind" and "as" introducing a clause (like "that" commonly does).

Comment: I don't see any problem with ***such as was*** (just a slightly fancy way of saying ***that was*** in the cited context). But *a condition of very cold* is distractingly weird. I expect *a condition of...* to be followed by a ***noun*** - as in *a condition of **employment** ...of **being free** ...of **being very cold.*** Where ***being*** is a gerund noun usage that can be *followed* by an adjective.

Comment: Welcome to SE EL&U. If you read the [Tour] carefully you will see that this sort of question is not really suitable for this site, but might be appropriate for SE English Language Learners.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Compare it to this (made-up) passage:

> The man had a very well formed and highly developed notion of extreme cold, but the dog didn’t. No, the dog had no **such sharp consciousness**.

That’s basically what London means. Another example of the same kind of use of *such* is:

> Although John swore he had seen an elephant-sized animal hovering like a hummingbird, she doubted the existence—and even the possibility—of **such a creature**.